# Android Header and Footer not appearing with custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have the following code:

```
    public class RefreshView extends ListView { 

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private RelativeLayout mHeaderView;
    private RelativeLayout mFooterView;

    public RefreshView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Refresh view
        mHeaderView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, this,
                true);
        addHeaderView(mHeaderView);

        mFooterView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, this,
                false);
        addFooterView(mFooterView, this, true);     
    }
}
```

And this is my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.merry.more.RefreshView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my `ListActivity` I call this on the oncreate:

```
mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
        mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I see all my listitems but no header footer. Any ideas? :o

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use

```
setAdapter(adapter);
```

instead of

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Just try... Hope it works..

setListAdapter() isn't a method you can call on an Activity (it is available on ListActivity but you're not using that). You're going to have to add a ListView into your layout (/res/layout/passwordscreen) and then find it and call setAdapter on that.

Comment: I typed "In my ListActivity I call this on the oncreate:"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are trying to do..

But in my case this works fine,..

```
 View header =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,null);
 View footer =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer,null);  

addHeaderView(header);
addFooterView(footer);
```

Comment: I am looking for alternatives so that I can fully customize the listview as well. I know the above works.

Comment: I think, you are trying to add relative layout as Header and Footer but, did you know the impact of that? Then what kind of data R.layout.footer and R.layout.header have?

Comment: In that case you have to pass attributes for the views in the header and footer and using that you can make a custom views for header and footers that views you can add it in your custom list...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are trying to create a custom ListView like this, just take a look at the Tutorial about [Header and Footer](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

It is better to inflate your `Header` and `Footer` in the `Activity` or `ListActivity` itself and then just add to the `ListView`.

Comment: I am looking for alternatives so that I can fully customize the listview as well.

Comment: Well you can customize the ListView just by customizing the views itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you want structure (stable header - scrollable list - stable footer). In this case you need extend not a `ListView`, but `LinearLayout`, add header, list and footer there, and provide `LayoutParams` for all of them.